# Find the sup and inf using characteristic property

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{\frac{(-1)^n+1}{n+1}+(-1)^n, n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ i found that that $\forall x\in A, x\in [-1,3]$

what is $x_{\varepsilon}\in A$ such that $\forall\varepsilon>0, 3-\varepsilon< x_{\varepsilon}\leq 3$

How to do ?

Thank you

Comment: Does your $\mathbb N$ start at zero or one?

Comment: @Bungo yes $\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ denote the sequence that generates $A$. First observe that for all odd $n$, $a_n=-1$ and for all even $n=2k$ (for some integer $k$), $a_n=\frac{2k+3}{2k+1}$. Furthermore, the subsequence $a_{2n}$ (even $n$ of $a_n$) is decreasing and bounded below by $1$.

Let $X_{\varepsilon}$ denote the set of all $x_{\epsilon}\in A$ such that $\forall \varepsilon>0$,$3-\varepsilon<x_{\varepsilon}\leq 3$. From the above observations we see that for $\varepsilon>4$ we have $3-\varepsilon<-1$ and $X_{\varepsilon}=A$. For $4\geq \varepsilon\geq2$ we have $-1\leq 3-\varepsilon\leq1$ and $X_{\varepsilon}$ is the set generated by $a_{2n}$. Now all that's left is the case $\varepsilon < 2$.

We want to know the greatest $k$ such that $\frac{2k+3}{2k+1}>3-\varepsilon$. This is given by $$2k+3>(3-\varepsilon)(2k+1)\longrightarrow-4k>-\varepsilon(2k+1)\longrightarrow k<\dfrac{\varepsilon}{4-2\varepsilon}$$
Let $K_{\varepsilon}$ be the set of all natural numbers less than $\frac{\varepsilon}{4-2\varepsilon}$. $K_{\varepsilon}$ is guaranteed to have at least one element $(k=0)$ when $\varepsilon < 2$. It is also bounded above so $\sup K_{\varepsilon}$ exists. Then for $\varepsilon < 2$ we have $X_{\varepsilon}$ is the set generated by $a_{2n}$ for $n<\sup K_{\varepsilon}$.